# Implementing The SliderPicker from react-color library

Tags: reactjs, colors, jsx, color-picker, react-color

I can't find a proper example on how to implement the SliderPicker as a functional component, any suggestions?

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import "../Styles/Pixel-editor.scss"
import { HuePicker,SliderPicker } from 'react-color';

function App(){
  return(<div className="App"><SliderPicker/> </div>);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a state with object, which has a *hex* property. Then you can set it with *onChangeComplete* property:

```
const [color, setColor] = React.useState({ hex: "#FFFFFF" });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <SliderPicker
        color={color}
        onChangeComplete={(color) => setColor(color)}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-resonance-5il68w

Comment: for some reason i implemented the same code of the example that you show , nevertheless the SliderPicker didn't render properly. I'm declaring the component <SliderPicker> under another that is not the <div className="App"> idk if that's the problem

Comment: What exactly is the problem?